# Where is build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3?

Tags: android-studio, repository, build.gradle, jcenter

I have Just installed Android Studio Version 2.1 Preview 3 (AI-143.2682553)
When I run my project I get an error, it says:

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3.
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0-alpha3/gradle-2.1.0-alpha3.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0-alpha3/gradle-2.1.0-alpha3.jar

When I look in the Jcenter repository it only has 2.1.0-alpha1 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

So I get why it can't find alpha3, but when I change the build.gradle to 2.1.0-alpha1 it says: 
"The projects is using an incompatible version of the android Gradle plugin.
To continue opening the project, the IDE will update the Android Gradle plugin to version 2.1.0-alpha3"

which doesn't seem to exist right ?

Answer (score 2):

> Android Plugin for Gradle version 1.5.0 does not support Instant Run. Please update to version 2.1.0-alpha3

I had the similar problem  and I fixed it by update it in android studio,just like this! 
[image: setting]

after update ,I find out the changes of gradle

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3'
   // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

 buildToolsVersion '24 rc1'//buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with 2.1.0-alpha3  .. my project cannot be complied ..I used earlier version 2.1.0-alpha1 @ http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-1-preview-1

By uninstalling and installing older version.
Hope that may help.

Comment: They just added gradle plugin 2.1.0-alpha3 to the jcenter repository, so no problemo anymore..